# Text not visible in my multi client chat GUI application?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, user-interface, client-server

**EDIT** I have implemented a Multi client chat server which eventually I will transform into an Emergency Response 'Server-Clients' ad hoc network. Currently, my program is up and running but in the chat window what I am typing in the text box is not appearing in the eventLog (neither of the clients or the server). I don't know what is causing that error?

How should I resolve this issue?

Here is some part of the code:

```
public class ServerGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener, WindowListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID =1L;
    // the stop and start buttons
    private JButton stopStart;
    // JTextArea for the communication interface
    private JTextArea commWin, eventLog;
    // the port number
    private JTextField tport;
    // My server
    private VServer serv;

    // server constructor
//
//
//
//      
        commWin = new JTextArea(120,120);
        commWin.setEditable(false);
        appendComm("VANET Communication Window.\n");
        middle.add(new JScrollPane(commWin));

        eventLog = new JTextArea(120,120);
        eventLog.setEditable(false);
        appendEvent("Events log.\n");
        middle.add(new JScrollPane(eventLog));

        add(middle);
//
//
//
    }

    // append message to the two JTextArea
    void appendComm(String str){
        commWin.append(str);
        commWin.setCaretPosition(commWin.getText().length() -1);
    }

    void appendEvent(String str){
        eventLog.append(str);
        eventLog.setCaretPosition(commWin.getText().length() -1);
    }

    // start or stop when clicked
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(serv !=null){
            serv.stop();
            serv = null;
            tport.setEditable(true);
            stopStart.setText("Start");
            return;
        }

        int port;
        try{
            port = Integer.parseInt(tport.getText().trim());
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            appendEvent("Invalid port number");
            return;
        }

        // create a new Server
        serv = new VServer(port, this);
        // and start it as a thread
        new ServerRunning().start();
        stopStart.setText("Stop");
        tport.setEditable(false);
    }

    // entry point to start the server
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        // start server at default port
        new ServerGUI(1234);
    }

    // in case X is clicked, the application closes
    // Connection needs to be closed as well to free the port
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        if(serv != null){
            try{
                serv.stop();
            } catch(Exception ec) {}
            serv = null;
        }

        // dispose the frame
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // Ignore the other WindowListener methods

    // a thread to run the server
    class ServerRunning extends Thread {
        public void run(){
            serv.start();
            // in case server fails
            stopStart.setText("Start");
            tport.setEditable(true);
            appendEvent("Server crashed\n");
            serv = null;
        }
    }
}
```

some parts of **ClientGUI.java** :

```
//
//

public class ClientGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID =1L;
    private JLabel label;
    private JTextField tfield;
    private JTextField tfieldserv, tport;
    private JButton signin, signoff, ActiveNodes;
    private JTextArea tarea;
    private boolean connected;
    private VClient client;
    private int defaultport;
    private String defaulthost;

    // Constructor receiving a socket number
    ClientGUI(String host, int port){
//
//
        // The upper panel
        JPanel upperPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
        // the server name and port number
        JPanel serverPort = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,5, 1,3));
        // the two JTextField with default value for server address and port number
        tfieldserv = new JTextField(host);
        tport = new JTextField("" + port);
        tport.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);

        serverPort.add(new JLabel("Server Address: "));
        serverPort.add(tfieldserv);
        serverPort.add(new JLabel("Port Number: "));
        serverPort.add(tport);
        serverPort.add(new JLabel(""));

        // adds the server and port fields to GUI
        upperPanel.add(serverPort);

        // the Label and TextField
        label = new JLabel("Enter your username below", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        upperPanel.add(label);
        tfield = new JTextField("Anonymous");
        tfield.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        upperPanel.add(tfield);
        add(upperPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // the Central Panel
        tarea = new JTextArea("VANET Disaster Management\n", 120, 120);
        JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        middlePanel.add(new JScrollPane(tarea));
        tarea.setEditable(false);
        add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // the three Buttons
        signin = new JButton("Sign In");
        signin.addActionListener(this);
        signoff = new JButton("Sign Off");
        signoff.addActionListener(this);
        signoff.setEnabled(false);          // You have to sign in before being able to sign off
        ActiveNodes = new JButton("Active Clients");
        ActiveNodes.addActionListener(this);
        ActiveNodes.setEnabled(false);      // You have to sign in before being able to see the Active Client list

        // the Lower Panel
        JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel();
        lowerPanel.add(signin);
        lowerPanel.add(signoff);
        lowerPanel.add(ActiveNodes);
        add(lowerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600,600);
        setVisible(true);
        tfield.requestFocus();
    }

    // to append text in the text area
    void append(String str){
        tarea.append(str);
        tarea.setCaretPosition(tarea.getText().length() -1);
    }

    // called by GUI if the connection fails
    void connectionFailed(){
        signin.setEnabled(true);
        signoff.setEnabled(false);
        ActiveNodes.setEnabled(false);
        label.setText("Enter your username below");
        tfield.setText("Anonymous");

        // reset port number and host name
        tport.setText("" +defaultport);
        tfieldserv.setText(defaulthost);

        // let the client modify them
        tfieldserv.setEditable(false);
        tport.setEditable(false);

        // don't react to a carriage return after the username
        tfield.removeActionListener(this);
        connected = false;
    }

    // Button or JTextField clicked
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object obj = e.getSource();
        if(obj == signoff) {
            client.sendMsg(new CommMessage(CommMessage.Signoff, ""));
            return;
        }
        if(obj == ActiveNodes) {
            client.sendMsg(new CommMessage(CommMessage.ActiveNodes, ""));
            return;
        }

        if(connected){
            client.sendMsg(new CommMessage(CommMessage.Message, ""));
            tfield.setText("");
            return;
        }

        if(obj == signin) {
//
//
//
//
            }

            // create a new client with GUI
            client = new VClient(serv, port, username, this);
            if(!client.start())
                return;
            tfield.setText("");
            label.setText("Enter your message below");
            connected = true;

            // disable sign in Button
            signin.setEnabled(false);
            // enable the two buttons
            signoff.setEnabled(true);
            ActiveNodes.setEnabled(true);
            // disable server and port JTextField
            tfieldserv.setEditable(false);
            tport.setEditable(false);
            // when the client enter a message
            tfield.addActionListener(this);
        }
    }

    // to start the whole thing
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClientGUI("localhost", 1234);
    }
}
```

Let me know in case other files are needed to understand the issue!
Files I have:

```
CommMessage.java
VServer.java
VClient.java
ServerGUI.java
ClientGUI.java
```

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION:**
so far it is just a chat server which I used as a starting point (as I'm new to Java programming) but I actually want to build an entire application here that has a central server (doing most of the work) and multiple clients communicating with it bi-directionally. For that, I need to incorporate *AUTHENTICATION* as well. My idea is: Remote client will send a connection request, server opens a socket, then client sends the first packet containing its name, IP, and port number. The server should match it with a pre-stored list of all registered clients and if it is one of them, allows the communication to move forward. Otherwise terminates the connection, kindly suggest how can I implement that in my code.

**P.S.** 'V' stands for VANET (Vehicular Ad Hoc NETwork - my project theme)

Comment: For the additional question, it's rellay hard to give you an implementation of an entire application without coding it, however take a look at netty library it'll handle the network part: https://netty.io/

Comment: @Emax thanks for your help! I've gone through the link you mentioned but actually, it's a bit too much for my application. I have a University project at hand so my scope is limited. I guess someone with a better grasp at Java multi threading client-server applications might advice better :-)

Comment: If you have to handle multiple connection i suggest you to don't use the old model one thread for one socket,  take a look at the NIO it's an asynchronous IO so you have only one thread that can handle a lot of connections (The NIO is part of the java base classes) for an example: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/socketchannel.html

Comment: @Emax It seems great concept-wise (may be because I've already built basic concepts of socket comm. over the last two months) but to implement I'll have to redo my code which I've written over a period of last three weeks. Now I don't want to leave that all behind and start from zero. I guess, i'll stick to my code and Eclipe Neon ;)

Comment: Moreover, as mentioned in the [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html) _If you need to manage thousands of open connections simultanously, which each only send a little data, for instance a chat server, implementing the server in NIO is probably an advantage._ My main app is not a chat server and I just have a few clients sending little data so no need for scalability!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll respond to the main question, there is a typo in your code

```
void appendEvent(String str){
    eventLog.append(str);
    eventLog.setCaretPosition(commWin.getText().length() -1);
                             // ^^^^ TYPO
}
```

should be

```
void appendEvent(String str){
    eventLog.append(str);
    eventLog.setCaretPosition(eventLog.getText().length() -1);
}
```